# Organizing csv data and computing average grades

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I have a sample csv data of classes and grades with over 500 rows and it looks something like this

```
courseid  title  teacher  avggpa  students As   Bs   Cs    Ds   Fs
101       Math   Stevens  3.15    105      25.2 45.1 16.7  10.1 2.9
101       Math   Stevens  2.98    95       20.2 30.1 30.5  11.5 5.4
101       Math   Smith    3.33    120      33.1 40.1 10.2  7.6  4.3
103      English Jane     3.55    108      20.5 16.2 16.5  20.5 10.2
103      English Jane     3.47    100      25.2 38.0 22.0  7.0  2.0
202      Science Roberts  2.67    80       12.0 35.0 27.5  12.5 8.3
```

(Pretend that those are comma separated, I just typed it up for formatting purposes. Also percentages don't add up to 100% but pretend they do)

so far what I have is:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    next(reader, None)                        #to skip header
    self.data = list(reader)

case_list = []
for entry in self.data:
    case = {'course_number': entry[1], 'course_title': entry[2], 'teacher': entry[3]... #and so on for each header
    case_list.append(case)
```

So I have a list of dictionaries where each dictionary entry is one row from the csv file.

My goal is to combine and average the avggpa and As, Bs, Cs, Ds, Fs from teachers who teach the same course more than once. So in my example, I would like to average the grades of Steven's and Jane's classes, and then represent that with a visual. If a teacher only teaches one course, I would also like to represent his grades with a visual.

I'm struggling with coming up with a method to determine if a teacher teaches more than one course. Something along the lines of looping through the list and checking if the courseid and teacher is already in the dictionary, and then calling a function to average the gpas if so, but I can't seem to think out the logic.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if more clarification is needed please let me know. If there is also a better approach to organizing the csv data than what I initially did, please let me know!

Comment: Unless you are asked not to, I suggest using Pandas for this project.

Comment: @DYZ It's a self project so I'll definitely take a look into Panda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, remember that lists start indexing at 0 so your line in which you add each entry is off by 1 in each field. Start at

```
entry[0]
```

Anyways, you've organised a list of dicts, where each dict represents the stats of a given course. For your purposes, it would probably be better to organise your information in a single dict where the key is a teacher's name and a course id and the value is their total stats for that course. To do that, you would initialise an empty dict and then iterate throw the rows of the csv, checking if there is already an entry in your dict for a given teacher/courseid and updating if so or adding if not. Something like this:

```
stats = {}
for entry in self.data:
    # Convert type
    entry[3] = float(entry[3])
    entry[4] = float(entry[4])
    # Check if this teacher is already in the dict
    if not entry[0] + entry[2] in stats:
        # Add a new row
        stats[entry[0] + entry[2]] = {'total_students':entry[4], 'weighted_gpa':entry[4]*entry[3]}
    else:
        # Update this row
        stats[entry[0] + entry[2]]['weighted_gpa'] = stats[entry[0] + entry[2]]['weighted_gpa'] + entry[4]*entry[3]
        stats[entry[0] + entry[2]]['total_students'] = stats[entry[0] + entry[2]]['total_students'] + entry[4]
```

Then you can run through the dictionary and get average gpas:

```
for teachercourse in stats:
    teachercourse['avg_gpa'] = teachercourse['weighted_gpa'] / teachercourse['total_students']
```

I kept it to average gpas for readability but you could add 'total_weighted_number_of_As' etc to get your full list of desired stats

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful! and I started my index at 1 since I was not interested in the first column of data, but I forgot to mention that

Comment: No worries! I was talking about this line  'case = {'course_number': entry[1]...' should be 'case = {'course_number': entry[0]...' and every other index should also have the index value decremented by 1

Comment: A few quick questions - in line 6, did you mean 'weighted_gpa' instead of 'weighted_total_gpa' ? and also I get a TypeError on line 9: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'. It's weird because If I do entry[4]*2 or 2*entry[3] it works fine

Comment: Ah yeah my oversight. When you're parsing a file, everything is read in as type string, and you can't multiply strings by each other. You could fix that by type converting entry[3] -> float(entry[3]). And yes, 'total_gpa' was a brainfart. I'll update the post with type protection.

Comment: The reason that 2*entry[3] worked by the way is that string-int multiplication is defined so that 3 * 'ab' == 'ababab'

Answer (score 1):

I think pandas is the right tool to do this job. Although I'm not an expert, after a quick google search I came up with this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',')
grouped = df.groupby(['title', 'teacher'])
average = grouped[['avgpa', 'As', 'Bs', 'Cs', 'Ds', 'Fs']].mean()
```

That should be right and is only 4 lines long. I hope that was helpful for you.